# NoSuchMethodError using AmazonS3Client

Tags: android, amazon-s3

I'm getting a NoSuchMethodError because the aws sdk is using a API Level 9 method, namely http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/SSLContext.html#getDefault() and the SDK is supposed to support API Level 7.

```
12-19 19:05:38.621: E/AndroidRuntime(15406): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-19 19:05:38.621: E/AndroidRuntime(15406): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getDefault
12-19 19:05:38.621: E/AndroidRuntime(15406):    at com.amazonaws.http.HttpClientFactory.createHttpClient(HttpClientFactory.java:94)
12-19 19:05:38.621: E/AndroidRuntime(15406):    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.<init>(AmazonHttpClient.java:122)
12-19 19:05:38.621: E/AndroidRuntime(15406):    at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.<init>(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:64)
12-19 19:05:38.621: E/AndroidRuntime(15406):    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.<init>(AmazonS3Client.java:305)
12-19 19:05:38.621: E/AndroidRuntime(15406):    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.<init>(AmazonS3Client.java:287)
```

Should I report this problem?
How can I temporarily fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to include the third party libs from within the aws-distro into your classpath. I have a working S3 App with api level 8.

Comment: Do you use the AmazonS3Client class? What libs should I include?

Comment: download and unpack aws-java-sdk-1.6.9.zip and take aws-java-sdk-1.6.9/third-party/*/*.jar into the lib dir of your android project.

Comment: I've got an answer from the amazon support and they said that their sdk is only supporting api level 10+ now.